# How to run the FourQ lib by Microsoft at 32-Bit?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, compilation, cross-compiling, elliptic-curve

I figured out how to run FourQ at 64-Bit, but now I want to run it through 32-Bit architecture. First of all the lib can be found at [1].
I'm running the stuff from "FourQ_x64_and_portable" directory. If I try the command, as suggested in the readme:

```
make CC=gcc ARCH=x86
```

it will print me errors

```
FourQ_x64_and_portable>make CC=gcc ARCH=x86
gcc -c -O3        -D _X86_ -D __LINUX__         ecc_tests.c
In file included from FourQ_internal.h:25:0,
                 from ecc_tests.c:15:
FourQ.h:137:6: error: #error -- "Unsupported configuration"
     #error -- "Unsupported configuration"
      ^
In file included from ecc_tests.c:15:0:
FourQ_internal.h:39:6: error: #error -- "Unsupported configuration"
     #error -- "Unsupported configuration"
      ^
make: *** [ecc_tests.o] Error 1
```

Well this is not wondering, I'm using Windows 10 x64 with MinGW at 32 and 64 Bits. I wrote a batch file for changing between x64 and x86, therefore, this is not the problem.

If I modify the makefile, by suggestions given from fourQ.h, and insert an input type for OS (OS==WIN? OS=**WINDOWS** : OS=**LINUX**) and run it again, it turns me out an error again.

```
FourQ_x64_and_portable>make CC=gcc OS=WIN ARCH=x86
gcc -c -O3        -D _X86_ -D WIN         ecc_tests.c
In file included from FourQ_internal.h:25:0,
                 from ecc_tests.c:15:
FourQ.h:39:6: error: #error -- "Unsupported OS"
     #error -- "Unsupported OS"
      ^
FourQ.h:137:6: error: #error -- "Unsupported configuration"
     #error -- "Unsupported configuration"
      ^
In file included from ecc_tests.c:15:0:
FourQ_internal.h:39:6: error: #error -- "Unsupported configuration"
     #error -- "Unsupported configuration"
      ^
make: *** [ecc_tests.o] Error 1
```

Well this looks like, WINDOWS is not supported. I've installed Ubuntu in a virtual box and try to compile again, but the last time, it show me the same error. Any suggestions how to fix this issue?

BTW. some information about gcc:

```
>gcc -v
Target: mingw32
[...]
Thread model: win32
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)
```

Since I want to run this code (in the end) on an ARM Cortex M4, I can use "arm-none-eabi-gcc" instead of "gcc" for cross-compiling. I've added a routine in that makefile for this.

[1] https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/fourqlib/

Comment: Solution is: adding "GENERIC=TRUE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answere is to add "GENERIC=TRUE". That means I have to type in:

"make CC=gcc ARCH=x86 GENERIC=TRUE"

Now I can compile for ARM-Architecture.